# СУБД для iphone и ipad

Tags: ipad, мобильные-приложения, ios, iphone, мобильная-разработка

Здравствуйте, уважаемые форумчане. Несколько дней назад решил заняться разработкой мобильных приложений под iPhone и iPad. Поставил себе задачу. Разработать приложение, которое раз в некоторое время будет загружать с моего демо сайтика каталог товаров, сохранять у себя и предоставит пользователю просматривать содержимое каталога оффлайн.
По старинке подумал, что хранить загруженные товары буду в БД приложения.
Погуглив, нашел следующие СУБД:

1. HanDBase Database Manager
2. FileMaker
3. Bento

Расскажите, пожалуйста, впечатления, возникшие после работы с данными СУБД. Интересует следующее:

1. Какие есть подводные камни
2. Какую СУБД лучше использовать
3. Есть ли бесплатные аналоги
4. Актуально ли использовать СУБД в мобильных приложениях ? Если нет, какие альтернативы используют разработчики.

Заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы не слышали про CoreData? Это framework для работы с базой данных (и не только) от самой Apple. Очень удобный. Я бы советовал использовать его. Если, что вот ссылочка на официальный
[CoreData Guide.](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/cdProgrammingGuide.html)

А вот отличные [русскоязычные уроки.](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qu-gly5W33o&index=42&list=PL6724Ll8v6UhKUFEsQ9ol_gOI-ohCxgJp&spfreload=10)

Comment: Кроме того, что CoreData, это не СУБД, да, для таких целей CoreDat'ы c большой долей вероятности достаточно.

Comment: Да не то, что с большей долей вероятности, а гарантированно достаточно. К тому же каталог товаров будет выводиться с помощью UITableView или UICollectionView, а у CoreData есть такая замечательная штука как FetchedResultsController, которая делает работу с БД и таблицами (или коллекциями) фантастически удобной. 

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreData/Reference/NSFetchedResultsController_Class/

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7udWRLuK1YU&list=PL6724Ll8v6UhKUFEsQ9ol_gOI-ohCxgJp&index=45&spfreload=10

Comment: Большое всем Вам спасибо.